# How can I create a method that gets access to a Dependency Service and passes parameters to the method it called?

Tags: c#

I have a method that calls a dependency service.

```
DependencyService.Get<IPopUp>().Popup("XYZ", "ABC",
        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpTitleColor"],
        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpMessageColor"],
        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpBackgroundColor"],
        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpSeparatorColor"],
        (sen, args) => {
            DidShowFirstMessage = true;
        });
```

Interface:

```
public interface IPopUp
{
    void Popup(string title,
        string message,
        Color titleColor,
        Color messageColor,
        Color popUpBackgroundColor,
        Color popUpSeparatorColor,
        EventHandler handler);
}
```

Is there a way I could code a helper that would call the same dependency service and also add in the parameters.

**NOTE** that as the dependency service calls multiple versions of Popup I need to code the **Helper** so the parameters are hard code in there.  Not as an extension method to Popup. This is not a duplicate of my previously asked question. I just did not explain it fully before.

```
 Helper.Popup(("XYZ", "ABC", (sen, args) => {
            DidShowFirstMessage = true;
        });
```

Comment: @AliReza: see [EventHandler Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netframework-4.8): `public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);`

Comment: you right I didn't see the interface before.

Comment: @Alan2: if you didn't explain it fully before, why do you not edit your previous question and improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need? I'm not sure that I understand your problem here...

```cs
static class Helper
{
     public static void Popup (string xyz ,string abc ,EventHandler eh)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IPopUp>().Popup(xyz, abc,
         (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpTitleColor"],
         (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpMessageColor"],
         (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpBackgroundColor"],
         (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpSeparatorColor"],
         eh;
    }
}
```

usage

```cs
Helper.Popup("XYZ" , "ABC" , (sen, args) => DidShowFirstMessage = true );
```

but having an extention method could be a better option here :

```cs
static class Helper
{
     public static void Popup (this IDependencyService ds, string xyz ,string abc ,EventHandler eh)
    {
        ds.Get<IPopUp>().Popup(xyz, abc,
         (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpTitleColor"],
         (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpMessageColor"],
         (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpBackgroundColor"],
         (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpSeparatorColor"],
         eh;
    }
}
```

usage

```cs
DependencyService.Popup("XYZ" , "ABC" , (sen, args) => DidShowFirstMessage = true );
```